# Return the middle value from list in OCaml

Tags: list, recursion, ocaml

I have a list

> let derp = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5];;

Im such a beginner in this language that this may seem stupid, but if I wanted just the middle value (3), how would I return that?

Comment: there will always be 5 elements in this list, if that helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind to use [List](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html) module, then it can be done like this:

```
List.nth derp (List.length derp / 2);;
```

Comment: Could this be placed as a function?

Comment: Sure. This is a function that returns an element from the middle of a list: `let middle_el l = List.nth l (List.length l / 2);;`

Answer (score 1):

```
exception Error

let rec middle = function
    []    -> raise Error
  | [x]   -> x
  | x::tl -> middle (List.tl (List.rev tl))
```

Test :

```
# middle [1];;
- : int = 1
# middle [1;2];;
Exception: Error.
# middle [1;2;3];;
- : int = 2
# middle [1;2;3;4;5];;
- : int = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. You said, in your comments that there will always be 5 elements in this list.

1. First, you can use Pavel solution : `List.nth derp (List.length derp / 2);`. If you want to put it in a function, `let middle list = List.nth list(List.length derp / 2);`
2. The 2nd solution is to use pattern matching :

   `let middle list = match list with 
         | [] -> 0 
         | p :: q :: r :: s :: t -> r`

   Note that here, I assume that the list is a list of Int
3. The 3rd is a rewritten version of the first 1 solution, but here I suppose that you know the lenght of the list :

   `let rec middle list n = 
        if(n == 0) if(list.isEmpty) failwith "Empty List" else list.head 
        else middle list (n - 1)`

Comment: in the second solution, `Nil` is not the OCaml constructor for the empty list, this is `[]`. Moreover, why a special case for that, and not for lists with 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, ... elements? The pattern-matching is not more exhaustive than with a single case for 5 elements. The third solution is not complete if you don't specify the initial value of `n` before entering the recursion (`middle list 0` won't return the middle of a 5-elements list)

Comment: Well, gwen sais there always be 5 elements in the list.

Comment: Well, gwen said the list will always contain 5 elements. It's been a long time I never touched Ocaml.

Comment: I'm totally OK with the second branch of the pattern-matching, but if your assumption is that there is exactly 5 elements, you don't need to match against an empty list: either use only one branch (for 5 elements), or at least 3 (`| [] -> ... | p::q::r::s::t -> ... | _ -> ...`) to make the pattern matching complete. Also the current version of the 3d solution does not address the issue mentioned above and is not OCaml (do you want to say `List.head list`? Anyway, there's no `List.isEmpty` function)